# Setting a cell with a date format in phpspreadSheet

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I`'m trying to set some cells with date format in xslx(it's only a test script) file this way

```
<?php
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
    \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Cell::setValueBinder( new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\AdvancedValueBinder() );

    $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
    $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
    $sheet->setCellValue('A2',2);
    $sheet->setCellValue('A3',3);
    $sheet->setCellValue('A4',4);
    $sheet->setCellValue('A5',5);

    $time = gmmktime(0,0,0,12,31,2008);
    $sheet->setCellValue('B2', \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::PHPToExceldate($time));
    $sheet->setCellValue('B3', \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::PHPToExceldate($time));
    $sheet->setCellValue('B4', \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::PHPToExceldate($time));
    $sheet->setCellValue('B5', \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::PHPToExceldate($time));

    $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);

    if(file_exists('prueba.xlsx'))
        unlink('prueba.xlsx');


    $writer->save('prueba.xlsx');
```

but I get this error message

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::PHPToExceldate() in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba_excel\index.php on line 16

I've included the autoload  file, do I miss anything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Date and Datetime using PHPExcel function writes in excel as Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32944964/date-and-datetime-using-phpexcel-function-writes-in-excel-as-text)

Comment: The function you are invoking - Date::PHPToExceldate - does not exist in class Date. Try this function: public static function PHPToExcel($dateValue)

Comment: @lovelace I know it's not finding the function but  I'm using a doc  example and I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

you need to put the use **PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;** at the top of your php script, this way:

```
<?php
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
```